# websocket code not working on Prod Tomcat Server - 404 Error

Tags: java, tomcat, websocket

I am trying to run my first websocket app and refered [this link to get some sample code](https://dzone.com/articles/sample-java-web-socket-client) . I simply created `CustomEndPoint` , `WSClient` class , html file and then ran it on netbeans IDE and it was working like a charm.

I tried to deploy it on tomcat server whose url is accessible using `https` by changing `ws://` with `wss://` and it worked on my dev environment but when I deployed the same code on Production env its throwing below error in console:

> WebSocket connection to 'wss://xxxxxx-xxx.xxxx.**com**/websoc/ratesrv' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 404

For dev environment I below WS call is working :

`wsocket = new WebSocket("wss://dev_ip:8443/websoc/ratesrv");`

For Prod I am using(note the *.com* in url):

`wss://xxxxx-xxxxx.xx.com/websoc/ratesrv`

Do I need to explicitly provide the port number as well in PROD ?

Comment: It depends. The usual scenario in PROD is that you have a web layer (apache or any other web server that acts as a reverse proxy). That layer defines redirection rules, for example, request for xxxxxx-xxx.xxxx.com/websoc will be redirected to prod_ip:8443/websoc. In thtat case you don't need to specify port. What I suggest is to deploy a simple file (index.html) with your webapp and try to access xxxxxx-xxx.xxxx.com/websoc/index.html. If you get a 404 then the problem is not with the websocket but with the web layer redirection.

Comment: @MarcoA.Hernandez: I am able to access xxxxxx-xxx.xxxx.com/websoc/index.html when I deploy the war file

Comment: All your calls (to index.html and to websocket) are https? Can you try http calls? If you are using a reverse proxy, could you get direct acces to the tomcat?

Comment: @MarcoA.Hernandez: Yes, all are https. http are not allowed. We cant access Tomcat as well

Comment: Can you create a simple html page that test the websocket and give it to the Tomcat's owner to test the direct connection? Also, do you have the tomcat's deployment log to check if something went wrong?

Comment: does the port 8443 allowed in-out access on your server. many times server firewall adds restriction to port access.

Comment: @jeetendraMandal You can't get a 404 unless the port is open in the firewall. The problem is not the firewall, it is that the WS endpoint isn't running in Tomcat.

Answer (score 1):

Does your Tomcat version includes Websockets Runtime?

- If it does you must delete all the Websockets dependencies from your WAR. Ensure that you call mvn clean after change scope to provided.
- If not, you should include it. If you want to use Tyrus just put

> ```
> <dependency>
>     <groupId>org.glassfish.tyrus</groupId>
>     <artifactId>tyrus-container-servlet</artifactId>
>     <version>1.12</version>
> </dependency>
>
> <dependency>
>     <groupId>org.glassfish.tyrus</groupId>
>     <artifactId>tyrus-client</artifactId>
>     <version>1.12</version>
> </dependency>
> ```

And check that that there are no errors in the Tomcat console when deploy.

Comment: edited question heading. its working on one tomcat but not on the other

Comment: I tested some scenario and came back with new findings. Please have a look

Comment: Actually`tyrus-container-server`is sufficient. `tyrus-client` is a dependency of that and will be brought in automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the latest version of tomcat. 
[`tomcat8.5.20`](http://www-eu.apache.org/dist/tomcat/tomcat-8/v8.5.20/bin/apache-tomcat-8.5.20.tar.gz) worked for me.