# Java - how sockets how can I receive data without constantly pinging

Tags: java, php, sockets, tcp, udp

Okay, so I have an apache server that has text/data that I want to sendoff to a Java client. The issue is that the data will change often, and I don't want the client to constantly do a read on the server, because obviously I don't want a constant ping. I know that I can make a client socket but that requires my users to port forward to access the server, which isn't going to work for my users.

What I've found online is UDP punching may work or NAT Transfer, but I cant find any examples for how to do it in Java.

- If  you have any questions please feel free to comment :)

Comment: Can't you use server sent events or websockets?

Comment: I havn't found anything that will allow the server to respond randomly to the client. Because its an apache webserver I don't think you can do events.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could [Recieve Server-Sent Event notifications](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_serversentevents.asp), in which the server send the data, using PHP and JS as an example:

```
var source = new EventSource("demo_sse.php");
source.onmessage = function(event) {
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML += event.data + "<br>";
};
```

PHP:

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/event-stream');
header('Cache-Control: no-cache');

$time = date('r');
echo "data: The server time is: {$time}\n\n";
flush();
?>
```

Comment: Thank you, do you know how I could do an onmessage with Java as well?

Comment: Check this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31768349/how-does-server-sent-events-work

Comment: What you sent works well in java but thats assuming that I want a server, is there a way to get server events as a client in Java?

Comment: i dont understand what you want to achieve. Please elaborate.

Comment: So I checked out the java servlet for a while and used the doGet, but it doesn't seem to allow me to receive server-sent events. So in other words how would I be able to do what you did with javascript in java?

Comment: Check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10878243/sse-and-servlet-3-0 it have an example of a Java Servlet aquiring the data stream.